# Bounty for a question which reason is a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, support

What should I do with this question ([How to get distinct values from an array of objects in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15125920/how-to-get-distinct-values-from-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript)) and the offewring of a bounty by taking an answer of me ([ES6 - Removing duplicates from array of objects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53543030/1447675)) as reason to offer?

I can not answer the question, because it is in the kind of the bounty a clear duplicate question, but for the original question, it is older than any other answers of me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The questions are different. One is about one key, the other one about multiple ones. So these are *not duplicates*. I have no idea what this bounty is supposed to achieve. I'd just let it be.

Comment: Yeah, the bounty doesn't make any sense. Maybe the person [who made it](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3909481/sandeep-mishra) thought it was a way to post an answer while promoting it at the same time..? Who knows

Comment: Maybe. But in that case he'll loose 50 rep for plagiarism :)